# MySQL update company field with firstname and lastname field

Tags: mysql

My table has a field called 'company' and some have company names filled out, others do not. I need to fill the ones that do not with the firstname + lastname, these are other fields in the same table.

I am having a hard time figuring out what syntax to use. I want to use something like this, but I know its way off.

UPDATE * FROM 'table' IF company = '' WITH concat('firstname lastname')

I know this is way off, I have been looking on my own however I cannot find the syntax and I have a client breathing down my neck. I am not a developer. Im sure there are hundreds of examples I just cannot find them. I know this is simple for some of you guys/gals.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE `Table` SET company = IFNULL(company,CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname));
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/89c577/1)

This one should cover blanks/empty string.

```
UPDATE `table` SET company = CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) WHERE company IS NULL OR company = '';
```

Comment: Thanks, that did not work, also I found that the fields are not null they just have no values so I substituted NULL for ''

Comment: there i updated my answer with one that uses WHERE instead....and covers blank/empty string case

Comment: I used this one and it worked great! Thank a lot Tin, you even mentioned another answer over yours. However this one worked. Thanks a lot! I will study it to understand better.

Comment: The other answer would work too i think I am just not familiar with CONCAT_WS..hehe

Answer (score 1):

Use a `WHERE` statement:

```
UPDATE t FROM 'table' t
    SET company = CONCAT_WS(' ', firstname, lastname)
    WHERE company IS NULL OR company = '';
```

Comment: This one looks great. mine only handles null

Comment: 2 questions
 are the t's the field name? 
Should it be (firstname,' ' lastname) to provide a space in the middle of the names?

Comment: @illcrx . . . That is what `concat_ws()` does.  This version is better because it handles `NULL` values better -- instead of returning `NULL` it just ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Table SET company = CONCAT(firstname, '', lastname) WHERE company IS NULL
```